# Allow Web App Bot and Direct Line via ip restrictions to web app

Tags: azure-bot-service, azure-webapps

We do not have nsg (as described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-vnet?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)), and have [ip restrictions on our App Service (web app)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) linked to the Web App Bot. When we try to send a message using `Direct Line` token, we see 403 error.

Do we need to allow list a specific `Direct Line` or/and `Web App Bot` service tag in our app service?
We tried adding `AzureBotService` service tag but that doesn't resolve the issue.

[Question originally asked on github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/2090), got redirected here.

Comment: We have the same problem, were you able to find a workaround @dushyantp?

Comment: No workaround yet @RuiJarimba we are considering using nsg if no other way